# Select query from XML data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to get result from XML data but only getting a value of first node.

```
create table #temp(xmlString nvarchar(max))
insert into #temp (xmlString) values 
('<?xml version="1.0" ?><response status = "ERROR">
<error>Error1</error>
<error>Error2</error>
</response>')
```

I want a result :

```
Error1, Error2
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: How did your attempt to solve this problem end up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
    x.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(128)') as value
from (select cast(xmlString as xml) as data from temp) as t
    outer apply t.data.nodes('/response/error') as x(c)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88652/18)

Comment: Thanks Roman, i got what i want from your answer thanks again

Answer (score 0):

correct answer

```
select STUFF((select ',' +  x.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') 
from (select cast(xmlString as xml) as data from #temp)
as t outer apply t.data.nodes('/response/error')
as x(c)for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as Errors
```